# Change background color of div, based on a dropdown list of hex codes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can I use jQuery to change the background of a `<div>` by selecting the HEX code from a separate dropdown list.

**HTML**

```
<select id="target">
  <option value="#c2c2c2">Grey</option>
  <option value="blue">Blue</option>
  <option value="red">Red</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Attach a *change* event to the dropdown options. Since the value of the dropdown will likely to be your hex code or color you can just pull that value and use it directly in a *css* call. Here is an example using jQuery.

**Update:**
Also, included is an example which uses the values of a table and responds to a `.hover` event [documented here](https://api.jquery.com/hover/). Here I select the table from it's id `#hoverTable` and selected a `td` cell then pulled it's html `$(this).html()` and assigned it to a variable that I passed into the new decoupled function `bgChange`. To change another element on the page simply change the selector in bgChange and QED.

**JavaScript (jQuery)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Function to change colors
    var bgChange = function (newColor) {
        $("body").css("background", newColor);
        return true;
    }

    $("#hoverTable td").hover(function(e){
        var color = $(this).html();
        bgChange(color);
    }, function(){
        bgChange("#FFF");
    });

    $( "#target" ).change(function() {
        var color = $("#target").val(); // Val is your hex code
        $("body").css("background", color);
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
<table id="hoverTable" class="table" >
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>ColorCode</th>
    <th>Misc</th>
  </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Bryce</td>
        <td>Blue</td>
        <td>Balloon</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Grey</td>
        <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Corey</td>
        <td>Red</td>
        <td>Cheese</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div> <!-- row -->

<select id="target">
  <option value="#c2c2c2">Grey</option>
  <option value="blue">Blue</option>
  <option value="red">Red</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Big help thanks. Though now I'm trying the same method for a table. Trying to change the styling of a div based on what <td> I hover over. `$( "td.colorCode" ).hover(function() {
  var color = $("td.colorCode").val(); // Val is your hex code
  $("#colorTooltip").css("background-color", color);
 });`

Comment: Are you trying to trigger this change on the `hover` event?

Comment: Yes. When I hover over the TD I want a div of that color to appear, like a tooltip of sorts.

Comment: Whenever possible you should include actual code with your question and take the time to make it as clear as possible so others will be able to find this answer later on.

Comment: The hover function requires two parameters so you'll need one for the mouse in and one for the mouse out. I'll update my answer to reflect this. And to make things more clear I'll decouple the background change function from the hover event handler.